# Template syntax error

Tags: c++, templates

EDIT: Fixed the error

This is my first time working with templates and am getting nasty syntax errors.  I have no idea where the error is since the compiler is telling me I am missing a semi-colon, followed by hundreds of errors.  Everything appears fine, however.  I am almost certain no semi-colons are missing.

Can anyone help me find this needle in a haystack??  PS The error occurs on the definition of the constructor for the List and says missing ';' before '<' (i.e. the code below)

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
template <typename T>
friend class List<T>;

public:
//Default constructor
Node();

//Copy constructor
Node(const Node<T> & copy);

//Overloaded assignment operator
Node<T> &operator=(const Node<T> & rhs);

//Destructor
~Node();

//Methods
T CreateNode(const T & T);
T &getData();

private:
//Data members
T data;
Node * mNext;
};
```

Comment: Is all this code really necessary? Can't you narrow it down?

Comment: If those definitions are in the header, they should probably be in the include guard. If not, they need to be part of the header.

Comment: @MrPickle5, See http://sscce.org. No one wants to look through tons of code to find an error when you can take an algorithmic approach to reduce it.

Comment: Sorry @chris.  I will try to reduce it, but the compiler error messages are not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee it's the *only* problem, but this certainly looks suspicious:

```
T &List<T>::Front() const
T &List<T>::Back() const
void Purge();
```

At a guess, you intended that to declare three separate functions, in which case it is missing a couple of semicolons, and should look more like this:

```
T &List<T>::Front() const;
T &List<T>::Back() const;
void Purge();
```

...or, quite possibly:

```
T &Front() const;
T &Back() const;
void Purge();
```

Comment: That is embarrassing and thank you.  It is still giving me the same errors, however.

Comment: @MrPickle5: I've patched together [a version](http://ideone.com/2ISJu3) that includes minimal definitions for the parts you left out, which compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.  It was in my node.h file.  The code was

```
friend class List<T>;
```

I removed the  and it worked. :)